# Normalization of k[x] in field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

This question is inspired by Exercise 9.7.L(a) of Vakil's *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*, but I think my question might be a more general one about terminology.  The statement of the exercise is

> Suppose $X = \operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ (with function field $k(x)$). Find its normalization in the field extension $k(y)$, where $y^2 = x^2 + x$.

Since $X$ is affine, I take it that this exercise is asking the reader to find the integral closure of $k[x]$ in $k(y)$, with respect to an inclusion $k[x] \to k(y)$ defined by $y^2 = x^2 + x$.  Maybe it's obvious, but I can't figure out what this inclusion $k[x] \to k(y)$ is supposed to be.  It can't factor through $k[x] \to k[y]$, by degree considerations, so $x$ must be sent to some element of $k(y)$ that's not in $k[y] \subseteq k(y)$.  But I can't figure out what the image of $x$ in $k(y)$ is meant to be here.  And I'm also not certain that I'm interpreting the problem statement correctly.

So the question is: am I misinterpreting the problem statement?  If not, what is the inclusion $k[x] \to k(y)$ that's being referred to?

Comment: The intention here is to consider the map $k[x]\to \operatorname{Frac}(k[x,y]/(y^2=x^2+x))$ which sends $x\mapsto x$ - the thing that's got you confused is just a typo where Vakil left $x$ out of the notation for the target field.

Comment: @KReiser aha! thank you, I've got it now.